# Convert GameObject back to generic type <T>

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, serialization, deserialization, deep-copy

I am implementing a deep object copier for Unity.

I found this great serialization/deserialization method here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/78612/3324388

However I hit a snag with MonoBehaviour objects. If the type is a GameObject, I need to use `Instantiate` instead of the serialization. So I've add a check:

```
if (typeof(T) == typeof(GameObject))
{
    GameObject clone = Instantiate(source as GameObject);
    T returnClone = clone as T;
    return returnClone;
}
```

I am able to cast the source as a GameObject (using `as`) but when I try to do it in reverse it fails with

> The type parameter `T` cannot be used with the `as` parameter because
>   it does not have a class type constraint nor a 'class' constraint.

If I try just casting it like:

```
if (typeof(T) == typeof(GameObject))
{
    GameObject clone = Instantiate(source as GameObject);
    T returnClone = (T)clone;
    return returnClone;
}
```

> Cannot convert GameObject to type `T`

I feel I'm close but I can't quite get the casting right. Do you know what I am missing to get this to work?

If I cast the type to conform the error still persists:
[image]

Comment: `return Instanciate(...)` ? Casting to a T makes no sens

Comment: In that case I get this error: [Error] The type `T' cannot be used as type parameter `T' in the generic type or method `UnityEngine.Object.Instantiate<T>(T)'. There is no boxing or type parameter conversion from `T' to `UnityEngine.Object'

Comment: Sounds like you need to constrain `T` whereever you are declaring it (you don’t show that) like `class MyClass<T> where T : GameObject { ... }`.

Comment: Yes I had thought of that but that will restrict this to not work with mixed objects that aren't GameObjects

Comment: Then make the constraint `where T : class`.

Comment: I still get the cast error when I do that. I posted an image to show.

Comment: `return (T)clone`

Comment: Doesn't work, says cast is redundant and it still cant do the conversion.

Comment: @Agressor Your `clone` object is of type GameObject, which, based on your condition, is the same as `T`.
Why are you casting `source` to a `GameObject` when sending it to the `Instantiate` method? Can't you simply do `T clone = Instantiate(source)`?

Comment: Sadly it won't cast, as mentioned above, none of that works with the errors posted above.

Comment: I'm going to assume you've tried `Convert.ChangeType(clone, T);`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `as T` in the return statement seems to do the trick. In the following test code attached to a game object in the scene I see a clone of `Test` and the console shows me different values for `Count`:

```
public class Test : MonoBehaviour
{
    private static bool _cloned = false;

    public static T Clone<T>(T source) where T : class 
    {
        if (typeof(T) == typeof(GameObject))
        {
            GameObject clone = Instantiate(source as GameObject);
            return clone as T;
        }
        else if (typeof(T) == typeof(PlainType))
        {
            PlainType p = new PlainType();
            // clone code
            return p as T;
        }
        return null;
    }

    public class PlainType
    {
        private static int _counter = 0;
        public int Count = ++_counter;
        public string Text = "Counter = " + _counter;
    }

    public PlainType MyPlainType = new PlainType();

    void Update ()
    {
        if (!_cloned)
        {
            _cloned = true;
            Clone(gameObject);
            PlainType plainClone = Clone(MyPlainType);
            Debug.Log("Org = " + MyPlainType.Count + " Clone = " + plainClone.Count);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: This does exclude cloning any value type, but if that is not a problem it's definitely cleaner and prettier than the intermediate cast to `object`. @Aggressor

Answer (score 4):

It’s not pretty but you can force the compiler doing a previous reference conversion to `object`:

```
 public static T Clone<T>(T source)
 {
      if (source is GameObject)
      {
          return (T)(object)Instantiate((GameObject)(object)source);  
      }
      else ...
  }
```

Yes, it is a bit of hack but sometimes you can’t avoid it. As a general rule, when you start mixing generics with runtime type checks things tend to get messy, a sure sign that you probably shouldn’t be using generics to begin with. Sometimes though, it can be justified but ugly code tends to crop up.

Comment: Works, but I prefer the `return p as T;` solution in Kay's answer.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out how you figured this out but I draw a blank. Kudos. This works.

Comment: @Draco18s oops sorry, forgot to remove the `class` constraint. This works for any type.